# Sign up user and add to firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that signs up a user and stores them in the Firestore database. For now, everything is happening inside the fragment but I would like to move it to the repo and connect via the view model.

```
 fun signUp(){
    val username = binding.signUpUsername.editText!!.text.toString()
    val email = binding.singUpEmail.editText!!.text.toString()
    val password = binding.signUpPassword.editText!!.text.toString()

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful){
                task.result.user!!.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener{
                    val newUser = User(uid = task.result.user!!.uid, username=username)
                    lifecycleScope.launch{
                        repository.addUser(newUser)
                    }.invokeOnCompletion {
                        Log.d("sign_up", "Your registration is successful: ${task.result.user!!.uid}")
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Account has been created. Confirm your email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        auth.signOut()
                        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginMainActivity::class.java))
                        finish()
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("sign_up", task.exception.toString())
            }
    }
}
 suspend fun addUser(user: User) {
    db.collection(Constants.USERS).document(user.uid).set(user).await()
}
```

My question is how to invoke suspend function *addUser()* inside my repo. Can I just create CoroutineScope inside my main function? Is it acceptable? I would like to do it correctly but I haven't found any solution.

Comment: Nice question, btw ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is how to invoke suspend function addUser() inside my repo.

Since you call `.await()`, your `addUser()` function it's mandatory to be defined as a `suspend` function. According to the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#extract-function-refactoring):

> Suspending functions can be used inside coroutines just like regular functions, but their additional feature is that they can, in turn, use other suspending functions to suspend the execution of a coroutine.

This basically means that a suspend function can **only** be called from within a coroutine body or from another suspend function.

> Can I just create CoroutineScope inside my main function? Is it acceptable?

No. As I understand from your question, you want to use a ViewModel along with a repository class. That being said, you have to move the `signUp()` function inside the repository class and leave all the staff that is related to the views inside your fragment class. Now I think that all it remains to be done is to call the `addUser()` function.

The simplest solution to solving this problem would be to define a sealed class that looks like this:

```
sealed class Response<out T> {
    object Loading: Response<Nothing>()

    data class Success<out T>(
        val data: T
    ): Response<T>()

    data class Failure<out T>(
        val errorMessage: String
    ): Response<T>()
}
```

Then the `signUp()` function should also be defined as a suspending function and the most important thing is to return a [Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html):

```
fun signUpInFirebase(email: String, password: String) = flow {
    emit(Response.Loading)
    val user = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await().user
    val newUser = User(uid = user?.uid, username=user?.displayName)
    addUser(newUser) //
    emit(Response.Succes(true))
}.catch { error ->
    error.message?.let { errorMessage ->
        emit(Response.Failure(errorMessage))
    }
}
```

Since this function is now suspendable, it can only be called from another suspend function, which is not the case, or from a coroutine body. Since the ViewModel is placed in between your views and the repository, it makes sense to launch a coroutine in the ViewModel class using a `viewModelScope` that exists inside the:

> implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"

To call this method from the ViewModel class, the following lines of code are needed:

```
fun signUp(email: String, password: String) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    repository.signUpInFirebase(email, password).collect { response ->
        emit(response)
    }
}
```

And inside your fragment:

```
val email = binding.singUpEmail.editText!!.text.toString().trim()
val password = binding.signUpPassword.editText!!.text.toString().trim()

private fun signUp(email, password) {
    viewModel.signUp(email, password).observe(this, { response ->
        when(response) {
            is Response.Loading -> {
                //Show ProgressBar
            }
            is Response.Success -> {
                    if(response.data) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "You're successfully authenticated.")
                    }
            }
            is Response.Failure -> {
                //Dismiss ProgressBar
                Log.d("TAG", "Failed with: " + response.errorMessage))
            }
        }
    })
}
```

That's pretty much of it!

Comment: Thanks, looks great. Can I use exactly the same for logging in?

Comment: Sure, why not? As long as you need to emit multiple events through a flow it wil work perfectly fine for any operation, including logging in.